# How to sort HTML tags alphabetically in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Hi I have a problem and i can not find a something on internet.
I have this tags:

```
<bratislava>...</bratislava>
<presov>...</presov>
<nitra>...</nitra>
<kosice>...</kosice>
<bardejov>...</bardejov>
```

and I want a simple way to sort the tags alphabetically using javascript.
Thanks.

Edit: I didn't wrote details:
I have these tags (I don't write it) some external JS code writes it and I want them alphabetically sorted.

Comment: I think that we need more details. A `HTML` example would be nice.

Comment: I have a text in my html tags and that tags have a custom name and i want to sort that tags alpabetically no that text but that tags btw that tags names are a city names in slovakia

Comment: @Filipko769 Are those tags to be sorted after the page has been loaded or do you want to sort them before sending the page as a response to a query? Can you add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the non-text nodes and refill the div with the cities nodes sorted.

```js
var citiesDiv = document.getElementById('cities');
var cities =   
  Array
  .from(citiesDiv.childNodes)
  .filter(item => item.nodeName && item.nodeName != '#text')
  .sort((a,b) =>
    (a.nodeName > b.nodeName) ? 1 : (a.nodeName < b.nodeName) ? -1 : 0
  );

cities.forEach(item => item.remove());                     // remove sorted elements
while(citiesDiv.firstChild) citiesDiv.firstChild.remove(); // remove other elements
cities.forEach(item => citiesDiv.appendChild(item));       // restore sorted elements
```

```html
<div id=cities>
<bratislava>City of Bratislava<br></bratislava>
<presov>Jurisdiction of Presov<br></presov>
<nitra>Restaraunts found in Nitra<br></nitra>
<kosice>Best Uber drivers in Kosice<br></kosice>
<bardejov>Wedding planners for Bardejov couples<br></bardejov>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused, how you ended up to this situation? Maybe you are not trying to do it right? What you are trying to achieve and how you ended up with HTML tags as those?

As those are custom tags, I think you generate them before rendering on document. I think, you should sort those tags before rendering, but I can't answer very well, before I know, what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by extracting data from the tags string using `RegExp` and then sort by your required order and then join them to getting the resulting string. Try this-

```js
const tags = `
<bratislava>...</bratislava>
<presov>...</presov>
<nitra>...</nitra>
<kosice>...</kosice>
<bardejov>...</bardejov>
`;

// Extracting the tags from the string and generate an array like
// [{tagName: 'bratislava', tag: <bratislava>...</bratislava>}]
const tagsArr = [...tags.matchAll(/^<([^>]+).*<\/\1>/mg)].map(([tag, name]) => ({tagName: name, tag}));

// sort the extracted array by tagName
tagsArr.sort((a, b) => a.tagName > b.tagName ? 1 : -1);

// Finally join them back for getting the sorted tags
const res = tagsArr.map(({tag}) => tag).join("\n");

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are multiple levels deep this could be an issue... otherwise:

```js
let doc, bod; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
const all = [...bod.querySelectorAll('*')];
all.sort((a, b)=>{
  return a.tagName > b.tagName;
});
for(let n of all){
  bod.appendChild(n);
}
}); // end load
```

```html
<bratislava>bratislava</bratislava>
<presov>presov</presov>
<nitra>nitra</nitra>
<kosice>kosice</kosice>
<bardejov>bardejov</bardejov>
```